# Clipping mask Problem- AI - CS4

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I am building mandalas on Illustrator using this method.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQUVn5Bv1M0

Simply put, he uses the polar grid tool to create a slice of whatever number of "spokes" you want, splits and joins the points to create a single path.  Then creates a symbol inside a symbol that contains a clipping mask so that when you draw outisde the lines of the slice you won't see it on the finished mandala.

I have followed this tutorial fairly preciesely and continue to experience this issue.

Here is what is happening.

I create my slice and duplicate with the rotate copy tool everything goes fine.  I have no gaps (see image 1) and I have my closed path with the clipping mask above my 2nd path to show me my bounding edges.

When I draw a line outside my clipping mask it throws my mask off and shows it "moved" even though i didn't move anything and have my layers locked.

I will include photos to show you what I mean.

- Image 1 - The mandala as it looks blank showing no skewing
- Image 2 -
  The Isolation mode instance of the slice showing my layers
- Image 3 -
  The test - when I draw outside the box in the slice Isolation mode
- Image 4 - What
  the mandala looks like if I do nothing showing the mask has shifted.
- Image 5 - If I trim the line this issue doesn't happen as much (what
  it SHOULD look like - notice the white gap missing...)
- Image 6 - one more example to show extremes

If I undo these lines that go outside the "mask" the shape returns to Image 1.

I must have a setting somewhere that I am unaware is on.  Please help.  There's no point to me having a clipping mask even on if I have to trim the damn lines everytime I make one.  Thank you in advance.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]
[image: Image 5]
[image: Image 6]

Comment: Tested Compound Path: Issue persists if I make the original path selection a compound path instead of a joined path.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you are doing and where your problems are. (I didn't watch more than 5 seconds of the video, it shouldn't be necessary). You should be aware Illustrator CS4 symbols are far more limited than Illustrator CC symbols. There have been *several* feature upgrades to symbols over the years. It's clear in the video Illustrator CC is in use.

Comment: Like you, I can't get Illustrator CS4 to play nice with this tutorial. It would seem the symbol is expanding to contain the strokes, despite the presence of a clipping mask.  However, it works fine in Illustrator CC.

Comment: Thank you.  So this issue is some sort of known bug then with CS4.  Is this with all use of clipping masks or is it just with the symbols?  All I am doing is creating a mask of the same pizza slice shape and then trying to draw in the isolation of the saved symbol so that it repeats through the rest of the mandala.

Comment: The issue is most likely due to *missing features* in CS4, not bugs.